# Generating BigInteger digits then multiplying.

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger

I'm trying to generate big integer numbers with X amount of digits.  I thought I had it figured out until I realized that the code below was creating Bits, not digits.  I've been trying to figure out a decent way of creating digits not bits.  Can someone help and point me in a right direction?  I haven't used BigInteger until now.  Oh this is a Homework question, that's why I'm asking for help, not an exact answer.  Thanks again guys.

```
BigInteger X = new BigInteger(23000, new Random());
BigInteger Y = new BigInteger(23001, new Random());
BigInteger result =  X.multiply(Y);
```

Comment: `10^(X-1)` (^ for power) will have X digits

Comment: The homework tag is deprecated. Please don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using here is a constructor of `BigInteger` that accepts an `int` and a `Random` and generates a `BigInteger` that is **uniformly distributed over the range** `0` to `(2^(numBits) - 1)`. [See BigInteger Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) - it will help you with your homework.

**EDIT:**

Maybe the following will help a little: a computer recognizes only two numbers: 0 and 1.

They are called **bits**.

8 bits represent an **octet**.

In most computer systems today, 8 bits also represent a **byte**.

So the following number: 010 in the base 2 (which is the base that the computer recognizes), which consists of 3 bits, equals in the base of 10 (which is widely used by people) to 3. 4 in the base 10
equals to 011 and 5 equals to 100 - hopefully you got the picture.

Using 3 bits to represent an number is the same as saying that you can represent a number ranging from 0 to (2^(3) - 1)=7. So, 3bits allow us to represent a number that has 1 digits. Using 4 bits will allow us to represent numbers that range from 0 to (2^(4) - 1)=15 - that is, numbers with two digits.

Now you need to think of a way that will tell you how to find the number of bits that will represent a number with `X` digits.

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking over it, still a little confused, but this helps.

Comment: @Scannn I'm happy that it did. I've added some explanation that may help you more.

Comment: @Michael : link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

`log2(10) =~ 3.321928`, so if you need 23000 decimal digits, you should specify 76404 bits (23000*3.321928).  Note that this will generate a number in the interval [0..10<sup>23000</sup>].  The number itself will probably not have 23000 digits.

If you want to force it to have 23000 digits you should generate a number in the range [0..10<sup>22999</sup>] and add 10<sup>22999</sup> to it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a array of char, each item of this array saves a digit. And you many need to implement a algorithm to multiply it.

If your homework needs to consider using less memory, you may want to use each char to store 2 digits or use one integer to store 9 digits.